# How to use a jwt.io provisioned token with jwcrypto?

Tags: python, jwt, jwcrypto

I am trying to use a [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) generated JWT within my python code using [jwcrypto](https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwt.html#examples) with some success.  I am saying some success because I am able to retrieve the claims (the wrong way) without validating the signature.

Here's my code

```
from jwcrypto import jwt, jwk

jwtIoToken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'

theJwt = jwt.JWT(jwt=jwtIoToken)
print(theJwt)
print(theJwt.token.objects)
```

The `jwtIoToken` value is taken verbatim from the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). I was expecting to be able to just do a `theJwt.claims` but it is set to `None`.   My hunch is that I need to validate the signature, but I have no idea how to do it without the key for which I have no clue what [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the key that jwt.io uses in the right column under "VERIFY SIGNATURE".
Unless you add anything different, the default value is "your-256-bit-secret".

[image]

When you use that value, you can verify the signature with the code below.

[jwcrypto](https://github.com/latchset/jwcrypto/) is a bit more complicated to use than pyjwt. Here you first have to initialize a `JWK` object and create the key from the given secret and then pass the key to the `verify(key)`-function:

```py
from jwcrypto import jws, jwk

jwtIoToken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'
key = jwk.JWK().from_password("your-256-bit-secret")

jwstoken = jws.JWS()
jwstoken.deserialize(jwtIoToken)
jwstoken.verify(key)
payload = jwstoken.payload

print(payload.decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use an alternative to `jwcrypto` named [`jwskate`](https://pypi.org/project/jwskate/).

`jwcrypto` quite convoluted imports and API make it unintuitive to use, as you have noticed, while `jwskate` has a more convenient and Pythonic API:

```py
from jwskate import Jwt, SymmetricJwk

# you can access the token contents, as a dict, without verifying the signature:
jwt = Jwt('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c')
assert jwt.claims == {'sub': '1234567890', 'name': 'John Doe', 'iat': 1516239022}
# or you can access individual claims this way
assert jwt['sub'] == jwt.sub == '1234567890'
assert jwt['name'] == jwt.name == 'John Doe'
from datetime import datetime, timezone
assert jwt.issued_at == datetime(2018, 1, 18, 1, 30, 22, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

# if you want to verify the signature:
key = SymmetricJwk.from_bytes(b"your-256-bit-secret")
assert jwt.verify_signature(key, alg="HS256")
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `jwskate`.